# how to get content of views by drag from first to next in android

Tags: android, swipe, drag

There are some views (buttons) in Activity, so I want to get content of views when the user drags his finger on the screen.

[image]

Comment: You want custom keyboard?

Comment: No, keyboard is to explain

Answer (score 1):

Add onTouchListener to your buttons.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // add button.getText() to inputString
                break;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
});
```